# uploading links to various trade websites using which webpart? What is the easiest way to accomplish this?

Tags: web-part

My company has a section which wants to upload 'new and relevant' articles to its' SP site. They use 7 very specific sites to gather their information from, which we search with targeted criteria through :site searches with google.  We will then compile a list of their top 5 returns for each site, and list them under that sites heading.

My question is this:

What is the best way / best webpart to use to display this information? I would like to mimick an RSS feed with this. Is there an easy way to do this?

I am just beginning with sharepoint, so please pardon the simplicity of this question.

Comment: By mimic an RSS feed, are you saying that you would look to provide a feed that can be consumed by other sources, i.e. outlook?

Comment: At what point is the collected data entered in SharePoint and how?  Is it all in one list with categories or spread out across multiple lists in multiple sites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would need to be a bit more specific with what data is where but from the information given it sounds like you would be working with either a [ListViewWebPart](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/list-view-web-part-HA010024052.aspx) or a [ContentQueryWebPart](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/display-data-from-multiple-lists-with-the-content-query-web-part-HA010174134.aspx).  The former would be for a single list and the latter would allow you to aggregate the information from lists in various SharePoint sites.

Comment: This seems to be somewhat in flux at the moment. Near as I can tell, I am going to need to run a third party software component to crawl the seven sites using search criteria. This will return hits into a SQL DB. I am going to code up a little thingy that will show them their hits, and they will be able to choose the five they wish to use in their SP site. Is it possible to interface this into SP in this manner?

For that matter, am I even making sense / explaining myself clearly?